# Get coupons from stripe in parse.com cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, stripe-payments

I am trying to connect to stripe and retrieve a coupon, but am not able to.  If I run either of these, I get an error.

```
Stripe.Coupons.retrieve(couponId, {
  success: function(coupon) {
    logger.log('debug', "coupon found", coupon);
    return callback(coupon, null);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    logger.log('debug', "coupon not found", error);
    return callback(null, error);
  }
});
```

I get back an error - invalid_request_error

or

```
Stripe.Coupons.retrieve({
  couponId: couponId
}, {
  success: function(coupon) {
    logger.log('debug', "coupon found", coupon);
    return callback(coupon, null);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    logger.log('debug', "coupon not found", error);
    return callback(null, error);
  }
});
```

I get back an error - couponId required

There does not seem to be any good documentation out there about how to accomplish this.

Comment: i know its a 2 year old question but i am searching for this issue from the last 4 days and no help. had you got any clue about that. This will be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why aren't you using parse.com guide? I am not strong with backbone.js but if you have a table called Coupons you can do this:

```
var Coupons = Parse.Object.extend("Coupons");
var couponsQuery = new Parse.Query(Coupons);
couponsQuery.equalTo(objectId,couponId);
couponsQuery.first.then(
      function(coupon)
      {
          //success, coupon object returned from query callbeck
      }
      function(error)
      {
          console.log("error: " + error.message);
      }
);
```

The code above uses promise, but you can use it in the old way like this:

```
couponsQuery.first.then(
      success: function(coupon)
      {
          //success, coupon object returned from query callbeck
      }
      error: function(error)
      {
          console.log("error: " + error.message);
      }
);
```

I hope this will help you.